# is_archive() returns false on the archives page

Tags: archives

I've followed the official documentation to create my archives page: http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Archive_Index

It works fine exept that "is_archive() returns false when I'm viewing this page.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because an "archives" *Page* is not an *archive index* of blog *Posts*, but rather a *Page*.

An "archives" page is simply a custom Page template, which applies to a static Page.

The `is_archive()` conditional returns true if an *archive index* is being displayed. An archive index page displays *Posts*, not static *Pages*.

**EDIT**

Instead of using `if ( is_archive() )`, try using `if ( is_page( 'archives' ) )` (assuming you've named your static Page *Archives*).

Alternately, you could use `if ( is_page_template( 'archives.php' ) )` (assuming you've named your *template file* as `archives.php`).

Answer (score 0):

The above solutions didn't work for me because I was doing this inside the loop. Instead I checked !is_single() to determine if I was on the post or the index :

`if ( 'post' == $ptype && !is_single() )`