# Trouble with conditional tags

Tags: theme-development, page-template, conditional-tags

I've got some code I want to run on every page other than the blog page and the archive page.

If I use

```
<?php if ( !is_home() )  { ?>
```

The code correctly doesn't show on the blog page.

If I use

```
<?php if ( !is_page('archive') )  { ?>
```

The code correctly doesn't show on the archive page.

But if I use

```
<?php if ( !is_home() || !is_page('archive') )  { ?>
```

The code incorrectly shows up on both the pages.

Any suggestion what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you haven't learned enough php ;) you should use && not ||

Comment: But it's either of those conditions I need, not both?

Comment: It's informative to check out the [de Morgan's rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws): `"not (A or B)" is the same as "(not A) and (not B)"` and `"not (A and B)" is the same as "(not A) or (not B)"`. So in short: *de Morgan rulez* ;-)

Comment: Thank you, that link is great. I had a feeling it was my logic but you don't know what you don't know until you know it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The codex is there to be used and should be your first stop. There is a complete page on [**conditional tags**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags)

To exclude the archive page, use [`is_archive()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_archive).

**EDIT 1**

Mark has a valid point. I didn't understand you well, and maybe myself as well :-)

Your problem is using the `||` and `&&` operators

Here is your code

```
 if ( !is_home() || !is_page('archive') )
```

OK. If you are not on the home page and not on the archive page, both return true, agreed,

```
 true || true
```

so your code executes as it should. Now, for instance, we are on the home page, so the check that we are not on the homepage return false, the following happens

```
false || true
```

Unlike what you think, your code should execute. This is not a flaw in your code, but how the `||` operator works. Only one true triggers and executes your code. The same happens when you are on the archive page.

The `&&` operator works like this with your code

```
 if ( !is_home() && !is_page('archive') )
```

If you are not on the home page and not on the archive page, both returns true and the code executes.

Now, when you are on either one of the home page or archive page, the one returns true, the other one false. Will your code still executes. The simple answer is **NO**

For the `&&` operator to trigger, all conditions **must return true**. Just one false fails your code from executing.

I hope this makes sense

** EDIT 2**

From your comments

> Incidentally, would `!(is_home() || is_page('archive'))` be the same as `!is_home() || !is_page('archive')` ?

No, it is not. You need to understand what the not (`!`) **[operator](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp) does. `!` infront of any variable or condition means the opposite of what follows afterwards. So, `!is_page()` would mean in simple English, "if we are not on a page", where as `is_page()` translates to "if we are on a page"

So, to look back at what I've explained in EDIT 1, lets look at the logic. I'll abbreviate `is_page( 'archive' )` to just `is_page()`

```
!(is_home() || is_page('archive'))
```

On any other page other that home and archive page, `!is_home()` returns true, and `is_page()` returns false, executing your code

```
true || false
```

On the home page, `!is_home` returns false, because we are on the home page. `is_page()` returns false, because we are not on a page.

```
false || false
```

So your code does not execute. Now on the archive page. `is_page()` will return true, while `!is_home()` will return true as well

```
true || true
```

So you are still stuffed. Your code still executes on archive page.

I want to leave you with this. Don't reinvent the wheel. The logic is already there. Go and check the links provided in my answer. You **should** be using `&&` and not `||`, no matter how you look at it, period

Comment: From the reading I've done, is_archive only works on archive posts, not the archive index. I should have been clear here, and I trimmed my code to make it more readable; the line of code is actually:

    <?php if ( !is_home() || !is_page('exhibition-archive') )  { ?>

where 'exhibition-archive' is the archives list page.

Comment: Also, I have done extensive reading of the codex, and especially the conditional tags page. As stated, individually, each of those checks are working as they should. It's when I put them together that its not doing what it should.

Comment: What do you mean archive index. `is_archive()` checks to if an archive page is being displayed. Please see the code link i've provided

Comment: This should explain what I mean: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22661/is-archive-returns-false-on-the-archives-page?newreg=50fdfe5531ce498390d20f08b0a0c29c

Comment: Please see my edit. This should be enough to explain

Comment: This is brilliant thank you. So Mark was right, although you were far more helpful. Conditional logic has always been a weak point for me.

Comment: Incidentally, would !(is_home() || is_page('archive')) be the same as !is_home() || !is_page('archive') ?

Comment: Please se my update. Also be so kind and accept my answer afterwards by clicking on the checkmark next to my answer in order to close the topic and keep this post constructive to everyone that find their way here. Many thanks :-)

Comment: Cool, thanks. Wasn't trying to reinvent the wheel just trying to figure out bigire's comment above that "not (A or B)" is the same as "(not A) and (not B)". No need to do any further updates, your initial edit was more than helpful, thanks!

Comment: Lol, ok. Ya, so `if( !is_home() || !is_page() )` is the same as `if ( !is_home() ) && if( !is_page() )`.  Enjoy! :-)