# I restricted wordpress by logged users. It's possible exclude a page?

Tags: php, homepage, content-restriction, logging

Here is my code for restrict my wordpress site:

```
function restrict_access_if_logged_out(){
  if (!is_user_logged_in() && !is_home()){
    $redirect = home_url() . '/wp-login.php?redirect_to=' . esc_url($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . urlencode($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]));
    wp_redirect( $redirect );
    exit;
  }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'restrict_access_if_logged_out', 3 );
```

Now I want to add one exception for example for URL: example.com/home-page.

Comment: Do you have a static front page set. As your code stands, in plain english it says, if the user is not logged in and if he is not on the homepage, redirect the user. What exactly do you need

Comment: Sorry, I did not explain well :( I answer the question if anyone cares.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wanted to restrict my website except a specific page. This is my solution:

```
function restrict_access_if_logged_out(){
  global $wp;
  if (!is_user_logged_in() && !is_home() && ($wp->query_vars['pagename'] != 'name-of-page') ){
    $redirect = home_url() . '/wp-login.php?redirect_to=' . esc_url($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . urlencode($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]));
    wp_redirect( $redirect );
    exit;
  }
}
```

Only I added this: `&& ($wp->query_vars['pagename'] != 'name-of-page')` in IF clause and a global variable `$wp` for exclude a specific page. This method avoid redirect when the pages is 'name-of-page'.

My inspiration [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-exclude-a-page).

And thanks @PieterGoosen for your solution in [your post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/155505/trouble-with-conditional-tags/155506#155506). :)

Comment: Hope that you understand me :)

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution, and +1 for the credits

Answer (score 0):

```
function restrict_access_if_logged_out(){
  if (!is_user_logged_in() || !is_home()){
    $redirect = home_url() . '/wp-login.php?redirect_to=' . esc_url($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . urlencode($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]));
    wp_redirect( $redirect );
    exit;
  }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'restrict_access_if_logged_out', 3 );
```

Rather than && use || with your conditional tag.

Comment: It doesn't work :( I don't know why

Comment: I don't think the problem is with AND or OR operators here. See my [post here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155506/31545) about this operators :-)

Comment: I had precisely found the solution to the problem but in a different way. Thanks anyway. If you want to answer the question, I will accept. Or I answer with my solution.

Comment: post it if you like