# Including 2 Negative Is_Template Conditionals in header.php

Tags: templates, conditional-tags

I want to set a conditional in `header.php` to wrap all of my templates, except `front-page.php` and `single-device.php`, in a bootstrap container element.

Writing one conditional achives what I want

```
if( !is_singular('device') ) {
   echo '<div class="container">';
}
```

However, when including two conditionals, only the first conditional applies.

```
if( !is_singular('device') || !is_front_page() ) {
   echo '<div class="container">';
}
```

Is the logic incorrect?

Comment: You should use the `AND` (`&&`) operator, not the `OR` (`||`) operator. `OR` operators need only one true to execute

Comment: Using && worked, but I am not following logic on that.  It is impossible to be on both front-page.php and single-device.php at the same time.  So it will always return one true

Comment: The `is_front_page()` check is somewhat faulty, depending on the context, see this [answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/30854/22534) for a alternative solution.

Comment: See [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155506/31545), I have explained the logic. Helps to break it down, it also confused me in the beginning :-)

Comment: @ialocin I still don't get the crappy logic around `is_front_page()`. As you said, the check is wrong. We just have to live with it I suppose :-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen For example when used with `pre_get_posts`, see [here](http://www.wpaustralia.org/wordpress-forums/topic/pre_get_posts-and-is_front_page/). Faulty is relative I guess...

Comment: So get this, when calling the same conditionals in footer.php (to close the </div>), I have to use || to get it to work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trouble with conditional tags](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/155505/trouble-with-conditional-tags)

Comment: You should play around with your `NOT` (`!`) operator

Answer (score -2, accepted):

*(Expanding on Pieter's comment above, and explaining the logic behind it...)*

`if()` evaluates the conditions in the parentheses, and that evaluation results in either `TRUE` or `FALSE` for the sum total (which can change, depending on how the various conditions are combined).

In plain English, `if( !is_singular('device') || !is_front_page() )` means, "If it's *either* true that this is not a single Device post, *or* true that this is not the front page, then..."

Since a URL on a WordPress site isn't going to both be the front page and a single post (unless you've gone out of your way to configure it as such, I suppose), you probably want to use `&&` instead: `if( !is_singular('device') && !is_front_page() ){}`

In plain English, the latter `if` statement means, "If it's *both* true that this is not a single Device post, *and* true that this is not the front page, then..."

Comment: Way to try and score points with someone else's answer...

Comment: I guess it is morally kind of questionable, but at the end, isn't this a collaborative effort to help people. @vancoder

Comment: vancoder... my rep wasn't high enough to comment on the question, and at the time I began writing it out as an answer Peter hadn't yet replied with his link explaining how the logic works out. I was just trying to help explain things.